# Need clarification in cakephp form validations based on conditions

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakephp. If I did any mistakes, Please kindly let me know. Thanks in advance.

I am having a form with 5 fields. In that, one form fields needs to validate based on the another field. for example, if i checked the check box, I need to validate the text field or else i don't want to validate. For this i did like, I set the validation rule for the text box first. If the check box is not checked, I will unset the validation field like this (`unset($this->model_name->validate['rule-name']);`). But, the problem is here. By default, check box is unchecked and also validation is set. so, I am getting the mandatory symbol. Even thought functionality working fine, I don't want that mandatory symbol by default. The mandatory field should come only when the form is submitted with checked check box.

Can anyone help me..?

Comment: May i know the reason for this down voting.?

Answer (score 0):

So you want a conditional validation rule?

In that case you need to write your own validation rule.

Take a look at the cakephp manual here

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods

In that function you can check for arguments passed ($this->request->data) and validate accordingly.